# How to change or add a download link to quickshare in alfresco share?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

It is possible to add a download link to the quickshare page? At the moment it is possible to have this link only if the server doesn't contain the plugin to preview the document. What I would like to do is add a download link the quickshare page or perhaps change the link itself such that it is a download link as opposed to a preview link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin by Andreas Steffan that adds a download link to the shared public page: http://www.contentreich.de/the-missing-alfresco-quickshare-download